# Redux - state updated in reducer but not updating the new values to component

Tags: reactjs, redux

While updating the state in redux combined with React app, the state is updated in the reducer. But in the container, I'm still getting the old state.

Below is the reducer.

```
import * as constants from '../actions/constants';

export function caseTypes(state=[], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case constants.LOAD_CASE_TYPES_SUCCESS:
      return action.caseTypes
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function cases(state=[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.LOAD_CASES_SUCCESS:
        const newState = Object.assign({}, state, {cases:action.cases})
        alert('newstate' + newState.cases)
        return newState;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

If I keep an alert inside the reducer "cases", I'm getting new values updated to the state. But in the component below, I'm still getting old state inside 
mapStateToProps function. Action is dispatched from the CaseSearchConnectComponent and mapStateToProps inside CaseSearchConnectComponent is also giving the old value.

```
class casePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div height="100px">
          <CaseSearchConnectComponent/>
        </div>
        {this.props.loadCaseList && 
          <div>
            <CaseListConnectComponent cases={this.props.cases}/>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  alert("case page cases  " + state.cases)
  return {
    cases:state.cases 
  };
}

const CasePageConnectComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(casePage);
export default CasePageConnectComponent;
```

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me how 'loadCaseList' is passed into casePage component? Also, do the alert inside mapStateToProps get called?

Comment: I would remove the alerts, and put console.log in two places: in the beginning of the render function of casePage, before the return, and in the reducer, just after case constants.LOAD_CASES_SUCCESS. Tell us what you find.

Comment: @AbhayShiro: Sorry, I missed the loadCaseList in mapStateToProps and reducer. The alert inside the mapStateToProps is called, but it does not return the value set in the reducer. But the alert inside the reducer gives the updated value.

Comment: Your intial state for `cases` is `state=[]` then after receiving action type LOAD_CASES_SUCCESS, you change it to an JSON object `{ cases: [..] }`. Is there any special reason for that? It causes a lot of confusions .

Comment: @ThoVu: No. I had just done that and there is no specific reason. Basically, caseTypes reducer function is called initially and I'm getting the value of caseTypes in the container. But, after "cases" reducer function is called, the alert in the reducer shows the cases value. But in my component, I could not get cases value. But, caseTypes is available, which was already added while page loading.

Answer (score -1):

You missed `mapDispatchToProps` after `mapStateToProps`.
`mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` are both pure functions that are provided the stores “state” and “dispatch” respectively. Furthermore, both functions have to return an object, whose keys will then be passed on as the props of the component they are connected to.

Consider this [documentation](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/) for your reference.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this solves the Problem. *mapDispatchToProps* is irrelevant here, you only need to use it if you want to dispatch actions with your component.

Comment: Oh, you are not providing `action`!!.  `action` is required where you `fetch` data through `API` and then passing those data to `reducer` where you set `state`. From reducer, your mapping state to props using `mapStateToProps`.  I think your reducer is been updated with proxy values. `Redux` won't work without action. `Action` and `Reducer` are the two building blocks for state management.

Comment: @Thananjaya, Thanks. Action has been passed and in the reducer, I could see the values from action updated to the state. The alert at reducer "alert('newstate' + newState.cases)" shows the new value. Action has been triggered from CaseSearchConnectComponent which is given in the CasePage Component.

Comment: Good. Mark my answer as correct one, if u wish. Happy hacking!